# Having trouble getting facebook like button to reload after jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have a div that fades out for X milliseconds then fades back in after an element is clicked. After the fade in, I re-initialize the facebook button. Everything seems to work great in Safari but in Firefox the facebook button disappears once the element is clicked.

```
$('.gall_thumb').click(function() {

    $(".gallery_rightframe").fadeOut(200, function() { // like button is in this div

        $(".gallery_rightframe").hide().delay(600).fadeIn(300);
        FB.XFBML.parse();   

    });

    return false;

});
```

I also have twitter and google+ buttons in this div and they all re-initialize fine. It's only the facebook button that does not show.

What am I doing wrong?